# change span count for the last few items in the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement bus booking seat layout and to complete this seat layout I am using Gridlayoutmanager with span count 4. But I need to get the last row seats with span count 5. Please help.

I have tried with get span size but not working properly.

Comment: What you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need 4 or 5 row in a column. Divide a column into (4*5) or 20 space. Then give 5 space(20/4) of last 5 sits and give 4 space(20/5) for other seats. For ex:

```
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 20);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position < TotalSeat-5)
                return 5;
            else return 4;
        }
    });
```

I think you may understand my idea.
Thanks